# Export images works in a wrong way Tibco spotfire

Tags: tibco, spotfire

I am developing a custom task for tibco spotfire. I need to export images from dxp programmatically. When image is too wide and has scroll I can get only visual bounds, instead of full image bounds. I am using:

```
Rectangle visualBounds = page.GetVisualBounds(visual);
```

Then I tried to export image to pdf, png, html using out of the box functionality (i.e. File->Export->To PDF) and got the same cut image. Is this a bug in spotfire, or I am mistaken?

Comment: Has this image been inserted into a text area or is it an image of a visualisation?